# How to show/modify the source directories dbx searches?

Tags: dbx

dbx keeps complaining it can't find the source code. How can i show/modify the source code directories dbx searches when looking for source file?

Comment: on the folder .dbx the file name project.json should cotain the artifact location and the workspace directory. 

Also using databricks ui you may see the file executing. with that filename and path you can use %sh ls -l /path-to-file/filename and see when was last modified

Answer (score 0):

(dbx) help use

use

use { + |  | '[' = ']' } ...

```
    Set the list of directories to be searched when looking
    for source files. If no argument is specified, the current
    list if directories to be searched is displayed.
```